# Tkinter stop similar tags from joining together

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I'm working on a dynamic scrolling application that somewhat emulates a table format. Unfortunately, due to the speed of the data, the only method that is quick enough to do this is the text widget ([Displaying real time stock data in a scrolling table in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938754/displaying-real-time-stock-data-in-a-scrolling-table-in-python)).

Ideally I would like to place a border of every around every "cell" to emulate column and row dividers in a table. However, it seems like similar tags join together if placed next to each other, meaning the border stretches out to the bottom of the text widget.

I have tried using 2 different tag identifiers to trick it into not joining the borders, but it still merges the borders/tags. However, if I change the colour or even the borderwidth to a different value, they no longer join up. Unfortunately, I need a uniform border width.

For a simple example,  I have defined 3 tags, 2 have identical properties, and one has a slight difference (colour) to show the effect.

The first two lines use the 2 identical tags for each cell, and the border is fully merged.

The 4th line shows the correct border, but this uses the tag with a different property (colour). The functionality I desire is to have the exact same properties but with a border per cell:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

# Define example tags, 2 with identical properties but different identifiers, one with a different property (colour)
text.tag_config("tag1", background="lightgray", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
text.tag_config("tag2", background="lightgray", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
text.tag_config("tag3", background="lightyellow", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")

# Insert 4 example lines
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "Line 1 Cell 1 Line 1 Cell 2 Line 1 Cell 3\n")
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "Line 2 Cell 1 Line 2 Cell 2 Line 2 Cell 3\n")
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "\n")
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "Line 4 Cell 1 Line 4 Cell 2 Line 4 Cell 3\n")

# Different tag identities with same properties "join up", so the borders are
text.tag_add("tag1", "1.0", "1.14")
text.tag_add("tag2", "1.14", "1.28")
text.tag_add("tag1", "1.28", "1.42")

# The tags also merge when on a new line, with the line above
text.tag_add("tag1", "2.0", "2.14")
text.tag_add("tag2", "2.14", "2.28")
text.tag_add("tag1", "2.28", "2.42")

# Line 4 has the correct borders, but only because colour for tag3 is different
text.tag_add("tag1", "4.0", "4.14")
text.tag_add("tag3", "4.14", "4.28")
text.tag_add("tag1", "4.28", "4.42")

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to debug if you didn't auto-update the data. If the question is about the appearance of tags, we don't need a constant stream of random data. Just add a few lines then leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks again for having a look. I have updated the code with a static and hopefully more clear example

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop tags from being merged. That is fundamental to how tags work in tkinter.

That being said, there are ways to emulate columns. For example, you can give each column a unique tag ("col1", "col2", etc), and/or give a tag to the characters between each column to create a break between columns.

Note: when you call the `insert` method you can give pairs of text and tags so that you don't have to add the tags after the fact.

For example, the following function will insert three values at the end of the text widget, adding the tags for each column and column separator. It will insert a blank line if all of the parameters are blank to emulate what your example is doing. This code uses the tags "col0", "col1", "col2", and "sep" rather than your more generic tag names.

```
def insert_row(col0="", col1="", col2=""):
    if col0 == "" and col1 == "" and col2 == "":
        text.insert("end", "\n")
    else:
        text.insert("end",
            col0, "col0", 
            "\t", "sep", 
            col1, "col1", 
            "\t", "sep", 
            col2, "col2", 
            "\n"
        )
```

Here is an example of its use:

```
insert_row("Line 1 Cell 1", "Line 1 Cell 2", "Line 1 Cell 3")
insert_row("Line 2 Cell 1", "Line 2 Cell 2", "Line 2 Cell 3")
insert_row()
insert_row("Line 3 Cell 1", "Line 3 Cell 2", "Line 3 Cell 3")
```

In the following screenshot I changed the color of the middle row to make it stand out:

[image: screenshot]